# mark dependencies provided with the gradle java mavenDeployer

Tags: java, deployment, gradle, maven-deploy-plugin

in a library jar deployment I need to mark a dependency as provided - otherwise I get

```
has an indirect dependency on Android API level BAR, but minSdkVersion for variant 'XYZ' is API level FOO
```

there seems to be a way with the war plugin, but I found no way to do it with the java plugin

the code/build-script is here: https://github.com/ligi/AndroidHelper

anyone knows a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite easy, you need to create a new configuration

```
    configurations {
      compileOnly
    }
```

than add the dependencies of this configuration to the source sets (otherwise compilation fails)

```
    sourceSets {
      main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
      }
      test {
        compileClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
      }
    }
```

The last thing is to tell your IDE that their is something additional, for example for Idea you have to use this

```
    idea {
      module {
        scopes.PROVIDED.plus += configurations.compileOnly
      }
    }
```

Now you can use the `compileOnly` configuration in your `dependencies` section as usual

Comment: thanks! that seems to work - just having problems with the last part - just having problems with the last part and AndroidStudio - seems only to work with IntelliJ

Comment: Ok. I expected that this will also work with AndroidStudio because it's based upon IntelliJ Idea

Comment: perhaps a change from v12->v13